# Update React component with placeholder replaced by another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component rendered via:

```
render() {
var props = this.props,
    config = props.config;

  return(
    <section className="prompt" data-component="prompt" style={{color: config.get('promptTextColor')}}>
      <div className="prompt-text-1 emphasis-font-web-safe">
        <DangerouslySetInnerHtml text={config.get('text1')} />
      </div>
    </section>
);
```

}

"text1" will be something like 
    `<div><ctaPlaceholder></ctaPlaceholder></div>`
and I want to replace that ctaPlaceholder with a different component (which is imported within the component I am rendering).

I have been able to replace just using normal javascript, basically just writing a replace function within `componentDidMount`, but would like to replace with the full component instead of just a string.

Thanks,

Update:

Eventually I have come up with putting this inside componentDidMount:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
  <CTA className="myClass" url={this.props.config.get('ctaUrl')} style={{color: this.props.config.get('submitColor')}}>Foo</CTA>
</Provider>, document.getElementsByTagName('cta')[0]);
```

I need to import store and provider in the file for this, which I don't think is specially clean as I had it before just in one place in my solution. But unless someone can help me with a better solution is they only way I was able to make it work

Comment: When do you want to replace the placeholder?

Comment: When rendering, I have come to a solution. Not ideal as I had before the store and the provider just in one class in my solution and now I have to import them, but it works

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to render the right component based on a prop or state, that's the react way.

I can't tell your specific use case, but the core for your use case will be something like this:

```
renderPlaceholder() {
   if (this.state.isCtaPlaceholder) {
     return <DangerouslySetInnerHtml text={config.get('text1')} />;
   } else {
     return <OtherComponent />
   }
}

render() {
  var props = this.props,
    config = props.config;

  return(
    <section className="prompt" data-component="prompt" style={{color: config.get('promptTextColor')}}>
      <div className="prompt-text-1 emphasis-font-web-safe">
        { this.renderPlaceholder() }
      </div>
    </section>
);
```

You just need to decide what to render based on **state/props**, when and the best to do i is always dependent on the specific use case.

Comment: Problem I'm facing is that I will have more divs as thext1 one, and some of them won't need to be replaced, some of them will need to be replaced but I won't know which ones in advance